# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ProfileInformation' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

Getting error:

> ERROR Type Error: Cannot read property `ProfileInformation` of undefined

```
<div class="ion-text-uppercase" style="text-transform: uppercase;">
    {{ userProfile.ProfileInformation.doctorName }}
</div>
```

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: please post ur userProfile.ProfileInformation declaration

Comment: var self = this;
  var doctorIn = self.db.collection('DoctorList').doc(localStorage.id)
   doctorIn.ref.onSnapshot(function(doc) {
     let userInfo = doc.data();
     self.userProfile = userInfo;
    })

Comment: @keshav godani  check `ProfileInformation ` is present or not   `ngIf="userProfile.ProfileInformation"`

Comment: <ion-item class="item item-block item-md">
       <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
        <img *ngIf="userProfile.ProfileInformation" class="profileImg" [src]="userProfile.ProfileInformation.doctorProfile" />
        <!-- <img *ngIf="!userProfile" class="profileImg" [src]="assets/imgs/default_user.jpeg" /> -->
       </ion-thumbnail><br><br>
       <div class="ion-text-uppercase" style="text-transform: uppercase;">
        {{ userProfile?.ProfileInformation?.doctorName }}
       </div>
      </ion-item>

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information that you provided, i can only suggest you to use **null check operator**:

```
<ion-item class="item item-block item-md">
    <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
        <img *ngIf="userProfile?.ProfileInformation" class="profileImg" [src]="userProfile.ProfileInformation.doctorProfile" />
        <!-- <img *ngIf="!userProfile" class="profileImg" [src]="assets/imgs/default_user.jpeg" /> -->
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="ion-text-uppercase" style="text-transform: uppercase;"> {{ userProfile?.ProfileInformation?.doctorName }} </div>
</ion-item>
```

That will help you to not get an error, but you still won't see anything while userProfile is undefined.

Comment: <ion-item class="item item-block item-md"> <ion-thumbnail slot="start"> <img *ngIf="userProfile.ProfileInformation" class="profileImg" [src]="userProfile.ProfileInformation.doctorProfile" /> <!-- <img *ngIf="!userProfile" class="profileImg" [src]="assets/imgs/default_user.jpeg" /> --> </ion-thumbnail><br><br> <div class="ion-text-uppercase" style="text-transform: uppercase;"> {{ userProfile?.ProfileInformation?.doctorName }} </div> </ion-item>

Comment: It's not working because you pasted wrong part of code, one second

Comment: Updated, please check

Comment: What do you mean it's not working, error is still present?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a condition and it will be  work.

```
<div class="ion-text-uppercase" style="text-transform: uppercase;" *ngIf="userProfile && userProfile.ProfileInformation">
    {{ userProfile.ProfileInformation.doctorName }}
</div>
```